# Insert or Update - web service design

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

If you're providing a web service that provides Add or Amend functionality for records in a database that has a unique key why would you not provide an "Insert or Update" method, in addition OR instead of two separate methods for Insert and Update?

**I'd be grateful if anyone could suggest what benefit the two separate methods provides to the client?**

Currently I'm focussed on the negative of forcing the client to have to hold state or to perform one request and then the other should it fail.

Having to store state, in my opinion, feels more prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid unwanted overrides.

When you intend to create a new record but instead override an existing one, data could get lost.

When you don't read the record before an update, there is no point in separating the two operations.

It depends on your situation.

Comment: Thank you.
As a unique identifier (personnel Id) is required, should the record exist we'd only ever want to update it. Any new personnel would have a new unique identifier.

I like the way you describe there being "no point in separating the two operations" as in this instance they've not offered us a method to read so the only way to check is to perform an "Add" request and handle the exception response.

I hope you'll excuse me not marking your response as the answer (yet) as I'd still like to see if anyone can offer any benefits of having two methods when the methods require a unique key.